# How do I get the pixeldata of an imageView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I want to get pixeldata of an imageView (i.e. all the pixels occupied by the imageView in an NSMutableArray) which I need in order to detect collisions between two imageViews.

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're doing some kind of color collision detection, you can use [CGRectContainsPoint, CGRectContainsRect](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-SW11) as a simple means of detecting collisions.

If you need to examine the pixels, you will need to get the [CGImage](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) of the image view's image and examine it with the methods it provides.

Answer (score 0):

Tak a look at the apple documentation page for getting the pixel data and then manipulating it.
[Technical Q&A QA1509
Getting the pixel data from a CGImage object](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html)

just use the [someUIImage CGImage] to get the CGImageRef of a certain UIImage which you must have plugged into your current UIImageView.